# XSLT multilevel grouping using Muenchian method

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Thanks in advance for your time. I have a deeply nested XML whose XSLT 1.0 transformation I need to perform (for pdf generation). I'm pasting the XML partially and I apologize for it already!

I have re-tweaked the XML as below based off a couple of answers and I realized I bumped into more issues. Thank you for your patience.

Please let me know if any additional clarification is needed.

**INPUT XML**:

```
 <Reports>
  <Report>
    <ReportID>R123</ReportID>
    <ReportName>R123Name</ReportName>
    <PurchaseTypes>
      <PurchaseType>
        <Name>Purchase Type 2</Name>
        <Areas>
          <Area>
            <AreaType>American</AreaType>
            <AreaName>IL</AreaName>
            <SaleDetails>
              <SaleDetail>
                <SaleDetailID>
                  SD45
                </SaleDetailID>
                <Amount>
                  177.3
                </Amount>
              </SaleDetail>
              <SaleDetail>
                <SaleDetailID>
                  SD56
                </SaleDetailID>
                <Amount>
                  123
                </Amount>
              </SaleDetail>
            </SaleDetails>
          </Area>
          <Area>
            <AreaType>American</AreaType>
            <AreaName>MN</AreaName>
            <SaleDetails>
              <SaleDetail>
                <SaleDetailID>
                  SD19
                </SaleDetailID>
                <Amount>
                  19
                </Amount>
              </SaleDetail>

            </SaleDetails>
          </Area>
        </Areas>
      </PurchaseType>
    </PurchaseTypes>
  </Report>
</Reports>
```

**Output needed similar to the image below**

Sample Image 2:
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/hxTUY6Qv_9eJyvxQ-UhQutMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

@DevNull, this is what I was trying:

```
  <xsl:template match="Report">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportID|PurchaseTypes/PurchaseType"></xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="PurchaseType">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Name|Areas/Area/AreaType"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
```

But I'm seeing the area type American twice.
Something like this:
R123
Purchase Type 2
American
American

Comment: Your requested output lacks necessary indentation, so it isn't possible to guess any grouping from it. Please, edit and correct.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre; I'm clarifying my question for additional details. That's the formatting that I need, but I'll try to re-indent it a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your input XML and the excel image of the desired output, it still doesn't look like you need grouping. The XML seems to already be organized the way you need your report(s) to be formatted.

Here's an example using XSL-FO to create the PDF.

Your XML input:

```
<Reports>
  <Report>
    <ReportID>R123</ReportID>
    <ReportName>R123Name</ReportName>
    <PurchaseTypes>
      <PurchaseType>
        <Name>Purchase Type 2</Name>
        <SaleDetails>
          <SaleDetail>
            <SaleDetailID>
              SD45
            </SaleDetailID>
            <Amount>
              177.3
            </Amount>
          </SaleDetail>
          <SaleDetail>
            <SaleDetailID>
              SD56
            </SaleDetailID>
            <Amount>
              123
            </Amount>
          </SaleDetail>
        </SaleDetails>
      </PurchaseType>
    </PurchaseTypes>
  </Report>
  <Report>
    <ReportID>R234</ReportID>
    <ReportName>R234Name</ReportName>
    <PurchaseTypes>
      <PurchaseType>
        <Name>Purchase Type 1</Name>
        <SaleDetails>
          <SaleDetail>
            <SaleDetailID>
              SD456
            </SaleDetailID>
            <Amount>
              17.3
            </Amount>
          </SaleDetail>
          <SaleDetail>
            <SaleDetailID>
              SD556
            </SaleDetailID>
            <Amount>
              23
            </Amount>
          </SaleDetail>
        </SaleDetails>
      </PurchaseType>
      <PurchaseType>
        <Name>Purchase Type 2</Name>
        <SaleDetails>
          <SaleDetail>
            <SaleDetailID>
              SD451
            </SaleDetailID>
            <Amount>
              12.2
            </Amount>
          </SaleDetail>
        </SaleDetails>
      </PurchaseType>
    </PurchaseTypes>
  </Report>
</Reports>
```

Transformed with this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="reportBorder" use-attribute-sets="reportPadding">
    <xsl:attribute name="border">solid 1pt black</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="reportPadding">
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-left">4pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-right">4pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-top">2pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-bottom">2pt</xsl:attribute>    
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:template match="Reports">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
          <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Report">
    <fo:table margin-bottom="12pt" border="solid 2pt black" width="2.5in">
      <fo:table-column column-number="1" width="1.5in"/>
      <fo:table-column column-number="2" width="1in"/>
      <fo:table-body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportID|PurchaseTypes/PurchaseType/Name"/>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ReportID">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell background-color="#FFFF00" border-top="solid 2pt black" border-left="solid 2pt black" xsl:use-attribute-sets="reportPadding">
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell border-top="solid 2pt black" border-right="solid 2pt black">
        <fo:block>&#xA0;</fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Name">
    <xsl:if test="ancestor-or-self::PurchaseType[preceding-sibling::PurchaseType]">
      <fo:table-row border-left="solid 2pt black">
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>&#xA0;</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>&#xA0;</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:if>
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell background-color="#DDA0DD" border-left="solid 2pt black" xsl:use-attribute-sets="reportPadding">
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell border-right="solid 2pt black">
        <fo:block>&#xA0;</fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>    
    <fo:table-row background-color="#8FBC8F">
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="reportBorder">
        <fo:block>Sale Detail ID</fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="reportBorder">
        <fo:block>Amount</fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::SaleDetails/SaleDetail"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SaleDetail">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="reportBorder">
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(SaleDetailID)"/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="reportBorder" text-align="right">
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Amount)"/></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces this PDF:

[image]

Hopefully what's happening isn't lost in the FO markup.

Comment: Thanks Zachary and DevNull. This is exactly what I'm looking for, but I apologize as I would like to request for some more explanation on this, as I'm still not 100% clear on this. As you may recollect, an earlier sample XML that I had posted had multiple levels of nesting. I'm editing my earlier XML one more time. I thank you for your patience as with your explanations my concepts are getting clearer and I can refine my question more. For the updated XML, I have mainly introduced another level of nesting to deal with my issue.

Comment: Can't do +2 for FO/PDF, so, just +1, sorry.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a grouping problem.  I'm very new to Meunchian myself, so I can't even really describe how to use it, so I'll defer to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key):

> Keys provide a way to work with documents that contain an implicit
>   cross-reference structure.

and [Jeni Tennison](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/):

> Grouping is a common problem in XSLT stylesheets: how do you take a
>   list of elements and arrange them into groups. There are two main
>   situations in which you need to do this:
>
> - grouping by content (e.g. group all the people from Nottingham together)
> - grouping by position (e.g. group 10 items per list)

Because all your data is very hierarchical, it's very easy to just work your way down the tree in one pass, moving from descendant group to descendant group.

Here's the complete solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="tab" select="'&#9;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Reports">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::Report"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Report">
    <xsl:value-of select="ReportID"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::PurchaseType"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PurchaseType">
    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:text>Sale Detail ID</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($tab,$tab)"/>
    <xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::SaleDetail"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SaleDetail">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(SaleDetailID)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($tab,$tab,$tab)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Amount)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the following (I had to convert the tabs to spaces for SO formatting).  The justification doesn't match your image:

```
R123
Purchase Type 2
Sale Detail ID              Amount
SD45                        177.3
SD56                        123

R234
Purchase Type 1
Sale Detail ID              Amount
SD456                       17.3
SD556                       23

Purchase Type 2
Sale Detail ID              Amount
SD451                       12.2
```

Comment: Thanks Zachary for your pointers. I think I didn't clarify myself properly. The thing is that it could be possible that a given report has sales only for brand type 1. Similary, the sale could be for only American area type etc. Hence, I was thinking about grouping.

If I try to use //BrandType, in essence I'll get the saledetail for both all brand types in the XML document, not just the brand type under that area type for a given report. I'm clarifying my question for additional details.

Comment: @questiontoask: Okay. Remember, selecting on `//BrandType` was just a starting suggestion.  As it stands, your question puts a lot of burden on someone trying to answer to figure out exactly what "...it could be possible that a given report has sales only for brand type 1. Similary, the sale..." means.  Can you provide a smaller, more specific XML source and appropriately formatted output that highlights these requirements?

Comment: I have shortened up the XML. Also, since I couldn't upload an image (as a new user), I have posted a picasa link where I uploaded the desired output image. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @questiontoask: Thanks for updating the soure and providing the image.  I've included the full solution which should answer the question.